Ubuntu 24.04 Gnome utilizing 10-45% GPU (RTX 4070) on external monitors
So whenever I connect my laptop (i9/16Gigs Ram/4070) to 2 external monitor, it utilizes the Nvidia GPU as stated by the manufacturer.
But the issue is, Gnome is using alot of GPU Compute. And I can see that like whenever I change the window, the zoom in and out animation is laggy.
Here is the nvtop Output,

I mean its a 4070, Rendering a UI should not need like 30 Percent of compute.
Unless Nvidia has a way to make us suffer.
Anyways lemme know if anyone can help. Really dont wanna see laggy animation. :(
Oh Oh, and as soon as I disconnect the USB C and HDMI cables from the laptop and the screeen comes back to the original laptop screen, RTX usage is 0% literally and it uses Integrated GPU and that too in a smooth way.
Edit 1
So turns out I was using Wayland and not X11. When I switched to X11, the Animation was smooth again but the usage was still there if I do something in desktop (Like change Windows or desktops)


